# Is there a way to get "Members" information for a Youtube channel

Tags: youtube-api, member

There is a relatively new function on Youtube channel called Channel memberships. You need to have at least 30,000 subscribers to enable this function. Members can "join" by sponsoring this channel each month.

I am interested in analyzing this Channel membership and studying user behaviors with this new function. However, when I tried to use Youtube Data API to collect members' information, it says the request is unauthorized.

I was wondering if there is a way to get a channel's sponsoring members' information. I was not sure if it is something that only the channel owner can view (i.e., need to log in using their google account to view this information).

Any help or information would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you find out anything?

Comment: It looks that information is kept only for the access of the channel owner.